# Multiple instances of a vue.js component and a hidden input file

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am experiencing a *weird* behavior using Vue.js 2.

I have a component that I reference twice in a single html page.
This component contains an input file control called `attachment_file`. I hide it using the Bootstrap class `hidden` and I open the file selection using another button. When a file is selected, I put in a variable called `attachment_filename` a certain string just like so:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button @click="selectAttachement"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-upload'></span></button>

        <input id="attachment_file" type="file" class="hidden" @change="attachmentSelected">

        {{attachment_filename}}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data () {
            return: {
                attachment_filename: null,
            }
        },

        methods: {
            selectAttachement () {
                $('#attachment_file').click();
            },

            attachmentSelected () {
                this.attachment_filename = 'some file here';
            },          
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Problem** With the class `hidden` and when a file is selected from the 2nd instance of the component, the value of `this.attachment_filename` is updated but in the data of 1st instance of the component!

If I remove the class `hidden`, it updates the value in the correct instance.

**Possible solution** use css `opacity` or `width` instead of the class `hidden`.

But is there a reason for this behavior?

Comment: You can use `v-show="false"` to hide an element. Side note: you should not use an `id` in a component because an id should be unique and only used on a single element.

Comment: Great didn't think of it before. Awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why it is not working specifically with `.hidden`, but you have an inherent problem in the code that i think is the cause of the problem.

You are selecting the input using jquery with an id, that creates a couple of problems:

1. When you use the component twice or more, all these inputs generated by these components will have the same id, which is not what you want since id should be unique
2. Even if you change it to a class instead of id, it won't work properly since you are selecting the element using jquery, and that will select all the elements with this class, while you want to select just the input in that component.

The solution is to use refs:

```
<input id="attachment_file" type="file" class="hidden" @change="attachmentSelected" ref="fileInput">

selectAttachement () {
    $(this.$refs.fileInput).click();
},
```

Comment: Great! No more id in components. It works even with class .hidden